# Правило постановки запятых при обособлении двумя тире

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Есть такая вещь, как обособление двумя тире. Используется для вставок, пояснений, иногда вместо круглых скобок.
Например:

*И он, опасливо — вдруг разозлится? — протянул ей конверт.*

Так вот, я не понимаю, по какому правилу нужно ставить запятые перед первым и перед вторым тире. Иногда я там запятые вижу, иногда нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правила известные, это Розенталь.**

Следует различать обособление **вставок** (которые не входят в состав предложения) и пояснительных конструкций, входящих в его состав.

(1) При обособление **вставок** всегда ставятся **два тире** (интонация исключительная), но при этом приходится определять наличие   запятых.

(2) При обособлении **приложений, пояснений и др.** одно тире может поглощаться запятой (интонация встроенная), что также регулируется правилами.

В приведенном примере используется **вставная** конструкция, так как это попутное замечание: И он опасливо — **вдруг разозлится?** — протянул ей конверт.

Коротко правило (1)  звучит так.

Если на месте вставок **не было знаков препинания**, то ставятся только два тире без запятых  (это наш случай).

**Первая запятая** относится а) к предшествующей части предложения (например, закрывает обособленный оборот),  или б) с обособления (например,  вводного слова) начинается вставка.

**Вторая запятая** а) или относится к структуре предложения и как бы **переносится** (например, она стояла перед сочинительным союзом), или б) закрывает обособленный член  в конце вставки.

Иногда две запятые ставятся по принципу **симметрии**.

Подробно это правило с примерами изложено **у Розенталя**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Пункт 4. В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые. Здесь возможны следующие случаи...

Comment: Откуда там запятая после слова *он*?

Comment: Наверное, случайно поставили.

Comment: На самом деле, поставил намеренно. Не знаю, правильно ли это, но мне показалось допустимым отделить "опасливо" запятыми, как если бы это был причастный оборот. Например, "И он, опасливо оглядевшись, протянул ей конверт".